# Sql Server 2008 - Convert localized DateTime column to UTC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, localization, utc

I have some columns in a few tables in my database that are all in the localized server DateTime values. I want to convert these all to UTC DateTime values (does not need to be DateTime2 since it will be assumed the new values will be in UTC).

I would like to do this in a single SQL statement. I am not entirely sure how to perform this as I do not spend a lot of time in the database.

Assumptions can be made that my table name is TestTable and my localized DateTime column is called TestDateTime.

I would want the script to do the update to the table as well as the conversion.

Any way to possibly do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can substract `getutcdate()` from `getdate()` to find the difference:

```
select  DateAdd(s,DateDiff(s, getdate(),getutcdate()), LocalizedDateColumn)
```

This assumes you are in the same summertime/wintertime state as the time you're trying to convert.   Not ideal, but the best conversion I know of that you can do in pure SQL.

A C# client has a much stronger conversion:

```
yourDateTime.ToUniversalTime()
```

Unlike the SQL version, the .NET version will correctly convert a wintertime date during the summer.

Comment: I am not super concerned with DST accuracy and I know my offset already. I presume I can do something like this: `select DATEADD(hour, 5, (select TestDateTime from TestTable))`

Comment: @Brandon: Yes, that would add 5 hours, like you'd expect :)

Comment: The final SQL was this: `update TestTable set TestDateTime = DATEADD(hour, 5, TestDateTime)`. Worked perfectly.